# continue with previous variable url when a link is pressed

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a URL that contains a fixed part, followed by an UUID id of an object.

```
http://localhost:8080/gym/7663e7c4-e3da-4ad3-a652-b00f7d138fb3
```

I have a button that links to a new page but the URL of the new page must be the same as the url of the current page (incl id) + /review
That way, I can get the id info in my mvc controller.

```
<a class="nav-link" th:href="@{review}">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Add review</button>
</a>
```

When I do this, I always end up with a URL without the id

```
http://localhost:8080/gym/review
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
th:href="@{/review}"
```

You need to add root to the path

Edit:  What about `th:href="@{__${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}__/review}`

Comment: If I do that, I end up at my root + review

    http://localhost:8080/review

That is not what I want, I want to end up here:

    http://localhost:8080/gym/7663e7c4-e3da-4ad3-a652-b00f7d138fb3/review